# Force on a charged particle inside magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have just started learning electrodynamics. And I came upon this expression telling force on a charged particle inside a magnetic field.

$$\vec F =q( \vec v ×\vec B) $$

where,
$F$ = Force on that charged particle.

$v$ = velocity of that particle.

$B$ = magnetic field.

My question is that I know magnetic field and electric filed are frame dependent, so here in this formula velocity ($v$) is respect to which frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula $\vec F =q( \vec v ×\vec B) $ is valid only for the frame where $\vec E=0$.

The actual formula for Lorentz Force is :

$$\vec F =q( \vec v ×\vec B +\vec E) $$

and this is valid for any frame.

Answer (score 1):

This formula (Lorentz force) is valid in any inertial frame. This means Lorentz force depends on inertial frame, it is not the same in all frames.

Answer (score 1):

It is the frame in which the charged particle's velocity is $v$ and in which the magnetic field is $\vec{B}$.

Both are transformed in other frames, and in general there will also be an additional force $q\vec{E'}$ in some other frame, because the B-field will transform into the sum of a new B-field and an electric field.

Note further that the force will not be the same in another frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is true , and it is classical electrodynamics. [The definition](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html#c1)

[image: magfor]

implies the frame where the particle is moving with velocity v, and there exists a static Magnetic field, the laboratory system.

(I do not know how to get vectors either)

See these real particles turning in the magnetic field in a [bubble chamber picture](https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm).

[image: pion]

> A classic example of a pimue decay

[see this for how](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/maspec.html#c2) the  centrifugal balances the magnetic force.